# Magento Create Module For Different Product View

Tags: magento, view, module

I am trying to create my first Magento module which would allow an attribute (yes/no) on a product page to alter the styling of the grouped products options on a product view page.

I'm probably starting a little too deep here but this is my understanding of how to do this:

- Create an attribute and assign to default attribute set (Alternative Group View alt_group_view).
- Create an alternative grouped.phtml file in /template/catalog/product/view/type - groupedAlt.phtml
- Create a basic module structure that initialises my module. I should really have the module create the attribute, but I havent a clue about that yet!!!

Then this is where I get stuck. Essentially I need to right the logic within the module file that looks for the attribute on the product - if its set I then need to code that tells the layout block presumably something that extends this:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
<reference name="product.info">
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
```

Hopefully that makes sense to someone?

I'm not sure that I can realisticly acheive this as Im just starting with module development although I have quite a lot of knowledge with the frontend and admin areas of Magento.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this through an observer. The event to observe is : 
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after

1°) In your module, in etc/config.xml, add your event handler :

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule_generate_blocks_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class> 
                    <method>generateBlocksAfter</method>
                </yourmodule_generate_blocks_after>                    
            </observers>                
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then create a Model named Observer.php in your Model directory (MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Observer.php)

In this model, add your generateBlocksAfter() method like this :

```
public function generateBlocksAfter($event)
{                      
$controller   = $event->getAction();
    //limit to the product view page 
    if($controller->getFullActionName() != 'catalog_product_view')
    {
        return;
    }
    $layout       = $controller->getLayout();
    $myblock = $layout->getBlock('product.info.grouped');

    $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');

    if ($_product->getAltGroupView()) {
        $myblock->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/groupedalt.phtml');
    }
}
```

And here you are.